# Why the color is totally different between background of the view and the drawable of item?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner of android. I have a problem. there are two line in different activity as following. the code for the color is same, but it show totally different color in the page. Could anyone tell me the reason?

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:height="10dp"
        android:drawable="#330000"
        android:end="10dp"
        android:start="10dp" />
</layer-list>
```

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/item_content"
        android:background="#330000"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: It's pretty strange that you don't get an error. Your layer list attribute android:drawable accepts only a drawable and not an hexadecimal. Could you explain what are you trying to do? Maybe I can help you.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot as well? Just for better explanation of problem .. .

Comment: @gcantoni   I replace "@color:gray" with specified color "#330000" for the attribute android:drawable. Just want to show I use the same color with the view. I am trying to fix a problem which reported by our product. They told me that the line color is totally different.

Comment: Are you able to post a couple of screenshots?

Comment: Sorry, I could not post the screenshots before the product online.

Answer (score 0):

I just recreated the xml and the colors look identical.
There really is no error but i would change the code just in case (add a shape object with solid background).

My guess is there might be more items in the layer list and one of them uses a color that has a transparent alpha value. This could blend the colors.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#330000"/>
            <size android:width="80dp" android:height="8dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```